# (small) incompatibilities between LuaTeX+hyperref (pdftitle)+accents

Tags: hyperref, luatex, accents

The following ECM works fine when compiled with XeLaTeX, but if compiled with LuaLaTeX there is a minor problem :
accented letter produces garbage in the pdftitle — but it's fine in the document .
I precise (after some tests) that it is not related to a particular font.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={àéèœ}}
\begin{document}
àéèœ
\end{document}
```

P.S. Maybe it's not relevant here, but in case : I'm on mac 10.6

Comment: After test, \`a \'e\`e\oe etc. do the work, but it's quite a pity to have to write this with an engine that support UTF8. Hence, I would ask for a nicer answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
```

Comment: It's work, thanks. Now the remaining question (it's only curiosity) is : why is it no problem with XeLaTeX ?

Comment: I believe that at the moment `hyperref` treats LuaTeX the same as pdfTeX, but contains dedicated code for XeTeX. But only Heiko could give a definitive answer.

Comment: XeTeX is using unicode by default.